# Why there is a "Case" pin in 905nm APD?

Tags: photodiode, pins, avalanche

In our research on minimizing the blockages in visible light communication using IRSs, we use a [MTAPD-06-013/014/015/016-905F](https://marktechopto.com/pdf/products/datasheet/MTAPD-06-013%20thru%20016-905F.pdf) 905nm avalanche photodiode which has 3pins.

What is the purpose of the "case" pin, and how does it connect to the circuit?

The anode is grounded and the cathode is connected to the amplifier.

Should we ground the "case" pin or can we leave that pin disconnected?

Answer (score 2):

> *Should we ground the "case" pin or can we leave that pin disconnected?*

You connect the case pin to your local 0 volts or local ground (not earth). Leaving the third pin disconnected is reducing the device's ability to counter electrical noise that may be present.